# How can open file in split, or if file is currently opened, focus a buffer in vim?

Tags: vim, buffer, neovim

For example, I have file `dwm.c`. If file is currently opened in any other buffer, I want to focus this buffer, otherwise I want to take other action like opening in vsplit.

I am making simple :Make command. If there will be any errors, errors will be in format file:line:column:...., I now have parsing of this done. When I will press space, I want to open the file on the line and column specified in error, so if file is not opened in any buffer, I want to open it, for example, in vertical split (new buffer). Otherwise, if file is opened in any buffer, I want to focus to this buffer and move to line and column. Everything except focusing an buffer (if exists) is done, I just want this focusing.

Comment: See `:help 'switchbuf'`.

Comment: `Everything except focusing an buffer (if exists) is done` Reinventing the wheel... There are `:h :make`, `:h 'errorformat'`, `:h quickfix.txt`, `:h 'switchbuf'` etc.

Comment: Reinventing the wheel, because wheel is done not for my needs. I want to learn some vimscript, and with this, I want to do some interactive :Make, which i would grow for my needs. I know, that ;make exists, but :make doesn't color syntax by default, I cannot move in produced output, I can't map keys to do something, I cant integrate it with my other plugins as I want. This is why I want to reinvent wheel, to make it better for me, and maybe for other users that want something working like this.